# Faster scrolling without onScroll?

Tags: javascript, performance, scroll, requestanimationframe, onscroll

I was getting really excited after reading [this article](https://gist.github.com/Warry/4254579) about faster scroll effects. I went implementing Warry's method to see if I could spot any difference in performance - compared to using the scroll event listener:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    console.log('Scrolling: ' + window.pageYOffset);
});
```

Code from article:

```
function loop() {
    if (lastPosition == window.pageYOffset) {
        requestAnimationFrame(loop);
        return false;
    } else lastPosition = window.pageYOffset;

    console.log('Scrolling: ' + window.pageYOffset);
    // make sticky calculations...

    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}
loop(); // start loop
```

These two pieces of code output the same (Y)offset and seem to be equivalent performance-wise. So my question is: Is the article right?

Also, how does `requestAnimationFrame` fits in this picture? I know that it tells the browser that it wishes to perform a re-paint. Or... is position fixed simply the way to go? I'm interested in this topic because I'm working on a plugin for sticky elements.

Any info or advice is appreciated!

Comment: "*seem to be equivalent performance-wise*" - how did you measure that?

Comment: The point is about more efficient *effects*. If you're just logging to the console, you won't feel a difference (apart from possible different number or logs).

Comment: The outputs were the same on each tick. I also toggled all rendering functionalities (Paint flashing, Layer borders, FPS meter and Scroll Performance Issues) on Chrome's DevTools to see how sticky elements would perform. There weren't any noticeable differences. I didn't write tests for this; just curious what others can tell me about this topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since scroll events can fire at a high rate, the event handler shouldn't execute computationally expensive operations such as DOM modifications. Instead, it is recommended to throttle the event using requestAnimationFrame, setTimeout or customEvent.

> It’s important to not only use requestAnimationFrame for your animations, but also to use it in the right way. - html5rocks

Also see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll

This is a nice little piece of code to get the right browser prefix. If `requestAnimationFrame` is unsupported, we fall back to `setTimeout(function(){}, 0)`.

```
var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame
    || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame
    || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame
    || window.msRequestAnimationFrame
    || window.oRequestAnimationFrame
    || function(callback){ setTimeout(callback, 0) };

// Usage
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    requestAnimationFrame(this.scroll); // call scroll event handler
});
```